# pytest monkeyPatch for an API function

Tags: python, pytest, google-analytics-api, monkeypatching

I am writing some tests and while working with an external API i have to create some function patches. Intentionally not the reserve engineer the API design but rather create a patch to exert similar behaviour during testing.

for example
consider 'requests' API, we can get the response form any URL by calling `requests.get('https:// URL')`. A patch for this function given in the monkeypatch [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/monkeypatch.html#monkeypatching-returned-objects-building-mock-classes).

Now consider a different API. Which is much more complex and have nesting functions. Now the question becomes how exactly we can create a patch for a nesting function.

Code Example

```
SomeAPIClass.function_1().function_2().execute()
```

Now the question is, how exactly I can create a patch for `execute()` function. MonkeyPatch does set an attribute for the given function but that just goes to `function_1()` as it would become `monkeypatch.setattr(SomeAPIClass, "function_1", mock_get)`

Comment: I added an answer. Could you check if it works on your side?

Answer (score 1):

We can [mock chained calls](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#mocking-chained-calls) by nesting the [.return_value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value), as documented:

> ```
> mock_backend.get_endpoint.return_value.create_call.return_value.start_call.return_value = mock_response
> ```

So for your case, it would be:

```
with patch('SomeAPIClass') as mock:  # Or if using pytest-mock, this could simply be <mock = mocker.patch('SomeAPIClass')>
    # To call: SomeAPIClass.function_1().function_2().execute()
    mock.function_1.return_value.function_2.return_value.execute.return_value = "Execution result!"

    # To call: SomeAPIClass().function_1().function_2().execute()
    mock.return_value.function_1.return_value.function_2.return_value.execute.return_value = "Execution result!"
```

#### Sample run

**src.py**

```
class SomeAPIClass:
    pass
```

**test_src.py**

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import src


# Using unittest.mock
def test_patch():
    with patch('src.SomeAPIClass') as mock:
        mock.function_1.return_value.function_2.return_value.execute.return_value = "Execution result!"
        assert src.SomeAPIClass.function_1().function_2().execute() == "Execution result!"

        mock.return_value.function_1.return_value.function_2.return_value.execute.return_value = "Execution result 2!"
        assert src.SomeAPIClass().function_1().function_2().execute() == "Execution result 2!"


# Using pytest-mock's mocker
def test_patch_2(mocker):
    mock = mocker.patch('src.SomeAPIClass')

    mock.function_1.return_value.function_2.return_value.execute.return_value = "Execution result!"
    assert src.SomeAPIClass.function_1().function_2().execute() == "Execution result!"

    mock.return_value.function_1.return_value.function_2.return_value.execute.return_value = "Execution result 2!"
    assert src.SomeAPIClass().function_1().function_2().execute() == "Execution result 2!"
```